# Vue-lazyload doesn't replace images on load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

[image]
I'm using `"vue-lazyload": "^3.0.0-rc.2"`,
here is config code

```
app.use(VuewLazyLoad, {
  lazyComponent: true,
  preLoad: 1.3,
  error: '/default-public/lazyload/image-url-avatar-alt.jfif',
  loading: '/default-public/lazyload/loading.gif',
  attemp: 1,
  adapter: { loading(){}

<img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" v-lazy:background-image="user.src_avatar['box-mini']" alt="">
```

the loading event is working properly but when loading the images, images are not replaced by loading.gif images (size 800kb)
Am I doing something wrong, I can't even find the gif in the browser's loaded images list

As for the error images, it has been replaced however it looks like it is flickering